# rescale a binary number

Tags: vhdl, hardware

How I can decode a 6 bit binary number(up to 32 in decimal) to a 7 bit binary number(up to 100)?

I want to change scale from 32 to 100 scale.

I am using VHDL-93.

For example if the binary number is 010000 it should show 50 in binary.

Comment: This makes no sense.  "Decoding" a 6 bit number into a 7 bit number is just setting bit 6 to 0 for unsigned, or setting bit 6 to bit 5 for signed.  There is nothing to decode since both have essentially the same format.

Comment: Note that at very similar question was asked previously at SO: [scale the value from 32 scale to 100 scale](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25045712/2352082).

Comment: Your title and your edited question still say "decoding", when you apparently (inferred from a comment) want to scale a number.  It is still confusing, since there is nothing to decode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said before, multiply by \$25_{10}=011001_2\$, either by hardware multiplier or manually by shift-and-add and then divide by \$8\$ by picking bits 3 to 9.

Simple asynchronous component (suitable for LEDs, not for fast logic):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity scaler is
    port(data_in:  in  std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
         data_out: out std_logic_vector(6 downto 0);
         );
end entity;

architecture structural of scaler is
    signal product: unsigned(11 downto 0);
begin
    product  <= unsigned("000000"&data_in)+unsigned("000"&data_in&"000")+unsigned("00"&data_in&"0000");
    data_out <= std_logic_vector(product)(9 downto 3);
end architecture
```

Comment: I don't find that prior answer (or comment)...?

Comment: @TDHofstetter Me neither, it was a few days ago, probably deleted by now.

Comment: @venny how I can multiply with a different base a binary number? and when you say 'divide by 8 by picking bits 3 to 9 'what do you mean? Can you please post code or example?

Comment: @user, multiply by **binary** 011001 (equals 25 base 10), then divide by 8 by discarding the least-significant bits, using Bit 3 as the new LSB (Bit 0) and Bit 4 as the new Bit 1, etc.

Comment: @user Did I answer your question?

Comment: @venny Thank you.Yes.What libraries I will need? I couldn't do that alone.Thank you for ur help

Comment: @user Answer updated. You will need std_logic_1164 and numeric_std. Feel free to hit 'accept answer' button.

Comment: @venny so this code will convert for example 32(6 bit) will show 100 (7 bit) and if it is 16 will show 50 ..etc and for decimals if it is 46.8 will make it round up 47 ? if it is 46.3 will show 46?

Comment: @user No, it will truncate to nearest lower integer.

Comment: @venny may I ask you if the six bit number is 16 it will give a result 50 ?

Comment: @user Yes, i have not tested it but it should work. Try it yourself, convert 16 to binary, write down the number three times, append zeros like in the code and add the three terms together. You will get 0001 1001 0000 and when you discard last three zeros, it is 50.

Comment: @user try std_logic_vector(product(9 downto 3));